# Spark: Cogroup RDDs fails in case of huge group

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, indexoutofboundsexception, illegalargumentexception

Good afternoon! I have a problem:

```
val rdd1: RDD[(key, value)] = ...
val rdd2: RDD[(key, othervalue)] = ...
```

I want to filter `rdd1` and throw away all elements, which are not in `rdd2`. I know two ways to do this.

First:

```
val keySet = rdd2.map(_.key).distinct().collect().toSet
rdd1.filter(x => keySet.contains(x))
```

It's not working because `keySet` is large and don't fit into memory.

Another one:

```
rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)
  .filter(x => x._2._2.nonEmpty)
  .flatMap(x => x._2._1)
```

here something happens and I get two kinds of errors (in different places of code): `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

I think that's because my groups are too large.

So how can I fix it? Is there any common method to fix such problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have  you considered using [`subtractByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) ?

something along the lines of

```
rdd1.map(x => (x, x))
    .subtractByKey(rdd2)
    .map((k,v) => k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider rdd1.subtractByKey( rdd1.subtractByKey(rdd2) ).
rdd1.subtractByKey(rdd2) will get those elements with keys which are in rdd1 but not in rdd2.  That's the opposite what you want.  subtractByKey-ing those will get exactly what you want.